# UITabbar only in Landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

Currently creating iPad app which display a Tabbar after login screen. So far successfully able to display tabbar and its related views, only problem is my tabbar is not appearing in landscape mode.

I want my application only in landscape orientation.

Please suggest me how to rotate the portrait tab bar to landscape tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:- For(Rotate one UIViewController in UITabBar) In viewWillAppear  and use CGAffineTransform

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
       //-- Adjust the status bar
       [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
       //-- Rotate the view
       CGAffineTransform toLandscape = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
       toLandscape = CGAffineTransformTranslate(toLandscape, +90.0, +90.0 );
       [self.view setTransform:toLandscape];
    }
```

Change in All project :- Copy and paste in all ViewController

```
1)

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations.
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }



   2) Change in Info.Plist 

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method in your all viewControlle.m file

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes, done that in all of my view Controllers. But still in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in all the relevant view controllers, make sure that your myProjectName-info.plist file specifies your chosen supported interface orientations:

[image]

You can also set this by selecting your Project in the Project Navigator (View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator), select your Target, and then the Summary tab, then press the desired orientation buttons:

[image]

Comment: :it's only sufficient for all orientation?

Comment: @MuditBajpai No, only choose the orientations which you require.

Comment: have you checked this for all orientation? i have checked. and only this would be not sufficient, you must implement the method what i have answered.

Comment: @MuditBajpai Yes, of course you need to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: too.  This answer is just part of the puzzle, just as yours is.